# How to create AJAX notification using PHP to notify friend request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, social-networking

I'm looking to create a AJAX growl or cool AJAX Web 2.0
notification, I know PHP, and I'm looking to notify users
when $username accepts friend request then a notification growl in AJAX
that notifies that the users has accepted their friend request.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is done through the use of [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), which involves more than PHP. In any case, it would be a matter of using your good ol' SQL query for checking the state of the request and giving the info to a polling-kind-of AJAX script.

Comment: +1 answer, use an ajax poller.  If you do want push technology, check out [Pusher](http://pusher.com) which is a web service that will handle realtime push events like this for your site.  They have a free plan and you can upgrade when ready.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for an answer, I'm going to try it out and see how it goes guys. Thanks